# why is my video not vertically aligned(flexbox)?

Tags: html, css

I was hoping someone could enlighten me why my video keeps floating on the top instead of aligning vertically?
I am using flex-box.

```
`.mainLogoAnimation{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
video{width: 100%;
} 

<body>
<div class="mainLogoAnimation">
 <a href="indexPage2.html"><video src="samples/Audio Branding - Arcade/ArcadeLogo_Stinger_03.mp4" id="javaPlayer"  autoplay loop muted></video> </a>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think you want `align-items` not `align-content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `align-items: center`.
2. Set the `height` of the `html` and `body` elements to 100%.

```css
.mainLogoAnimation {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainLogoAnimation">
  <a href="indexPage2.html"><video src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" id="javaPlayer"  autoplay loop muted></video> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! that explains a lot.

Comment: @Tofu No problem.